# Is it possible to use a loop variable to target a specific field entry?

Tags: variable, loop

I'm looping through the rows of a table field and hoping to target a specific field entry based on the `loop.index`. Here's a simplified example of what that might look like:

```
{% for row in entry.table %}   
   {% set foo = entry.field ~ loop.index %}
{% endfor %}
```

The doesn't work, but I’m curious if I just have the syntax wrong or if I’m thinking about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [subscript syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables):

`{{ entry['field' ~ loop.index] }}`

or the [`attribute`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function:

`{{ attribute(entry, 'field' ~ loop.index) }}`

The attribute function is more Twig-like in my opinion. But in this case it's only a matter of preference.

Other examples are:

`{{ myArray[0] }}` vs. `{{ myArray|first }}`
`{{ myString[0:1] }}` vs. `{{ myString|slice(0, 1) }}`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Twig has a nifty little [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) that does the trick. Here's how it works:

```
{% for row in entry.table %}   
   {% set foo = attribute(entry, 'fieldHandle' ~ loop.index) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Big hat tip to [Mr. Brad Bell](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/57/brad-bell) for posting the original answer in Stack Exchange.

Comment: You could also just use the [subscript syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables): `entry['field' ~ loop.index]`.

Comment: @carlcs I thought there might be a simpler way to accomplish that. That works like a charm and, to me, is a more elegant answer. You should post it so I can vote for it!